# Beautiful Soup (Python) not seeing text inside of span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out why BS4 is not seeing the text inside of the span in the following scenario:

- Page: https://pypi.org/project/requests/
- Text I'm looking for - number of stars on the left hand side (around 43,000 at the time of writing)

My code:

```py
stars = soup.find('span', {'class': 'github-repo-info__item', 'data-key': 'stargazers_count'}).text
```

also tried:

```py
stars = soup.find('span', {'class': 'github-repo-info__item', 'data-key': 'stargazers_count'}).get_text()
```

Both return an empty string `''`. The element itself seems to be located correctly (I can browse through parents / siblings in PyCharm debugger without a problem. Fetching text in other parts of the website also works perfectly fine. It's just the github-related stats that fail to fetch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this page use Javascript to load the page dynamically.So you couldn't get it directly by `response.text`

The source code of the page:
[image]

You could crawl the `API` directly:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/psf/requests')
print(r.json()["stargazers_count"])
```

Result:

```
43010
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bs4, we can't scrape stars rate.

After inspecting the site, please check response html.
There, there is class information named "github-repo-info__item", but there is no text information.

in this case, use `selenium`.